# Liferay, using serviceLocator in Journal article velocity template

Tags: liferay, velocity

I am trying to use serviceLocator in the velocity template for journal article in Liferay.
I modified the portal-ext.properties file by adding line:

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

Then i restarted the server

In my vm file I have:

```
#set ($countryService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.CountryService"))
#set ($countryList = $countryService.getCountries())
#foreach ($country in $countryList)
    $country.getName()
#end
```

This displays nothing in the article and also gives no error on the server. I also checked the database and countries are there and if I am using getCountries() method in my portlets service it returns countries as it should.

Has anybody had a similar problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.
In the portal-ext.properties firstly I was setting:

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

But instead that, it sholud be:

```
velocity.engine.restricted.variables=
```